# ngrx/effects errors not caught by global handler

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects

We have effects defined as:

```
@Effect()
  loadAll$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(actions.ActionTypes.LOAD_ALL)
    .map(action => action.payload)
    .switchMap((options) => {
      return this.service.loadAll(options)
        .map(all=> new actions.LoadAllCompleteAction(all))
        .catch(() => Observable.of(new actions.LoadAllFailureAction(null)));
    });
```

there is a reducer listening for `LoadAllFailureAction` and does changes to some flags in store.

Now, if in handling that action i do object destructuring of that null (sent in LoadAllFailuerAction), which producec TypeError, that error is not caught by GlobalErrorHandler (which catches uncaught exceptions). Also, effects stops running.

On the other hand, with exactly the same effects/reducers setup, if i manually do `throw Error()` in reducer, it does get caught.

Now that's a complete mystery for me.

Any thoughts?